# Android NDK - memory allocation test

Tags: android, memory-management, android-ndk

is there any simple way how to programatically test, how much memory can be natively allocated? Please, don't suggest some ready functions, I am asking for programable simple solution, if there is any (I haven't found anything)

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I am looking for something too, to verify broken memory mapping in my Transformer Prime tablet.